# How to set unnumbered subsection headings flush to left margin

Tags: sectioning

How can I set my subsection command so that the subsections are (1) unnumbered, and (2) flush against the left margin? (I can get numbered subsections to sit flush against the margin, but not unnumbered.)

Here is what I have been trying. It produces unnumbered, italicized subsection headings, but indented from the margin:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 11pt]{book}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bookman}    
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}


\usepackage{sectsty}  
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape\raggedright\large}  
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
```

Comment: Please do not post fragments of code only!

Comment: Completing your 'document' I find that  starred subsections are left aligned!

Answer (score 2):

May be I’m missing something, but why don’t you use the `secnumdepth` counter?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % unrelated to the question, but recommended
\usepackage{bookman}    
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\subsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape\large}  
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Genesis}\lipsum[1]
    \section{Abraham}\lipsum[2]
        \subsection{Sarah}
            Why is Sarah a sub-section of Abraham?
            This is sexism!
    \section{Isaac}  \lipsum[3]
    \section{Jacob}  \lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```